# Sorting Customer Struct In C

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have structure with most frequent words in huge text file, the field pointer array to char are words, and field count are their frequencies. My question is how to sort them from the longest word length to lowest -  to nicely display it to user? Code:

```
typedef struct pair {
char * a[20000];
int count[32000];
} Pair;
```

Example print:

```
printf("%d, %d, %d\n", bag.count[0], bag.count[1], bag.count[2]); // -> 8, 7, 3
printf("%s, %s, %s\n", bag.a[0], bag.a[1], bag.a[2]); // -> abbes, abbey, abhor
```

Comment: Why are `a` and `count` different size?

Comment: Why do you have a structure of arrays, and why are the arrays of different size? It's much easier to use an array of structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to turn the structure/array inside-out.

Having your arrays inside the `struct` does not feel right. Because you primarily have a pair of things, and secondarily you want one array of these things. Do you see what I mean?

It would look like this:

```
typedef struct pair
{
    char* word;
    int   count;
} Pair;

Pair pairs[32000];
```

You'd also need to know how many pairs are filled. (You would have needed this anyway.):

```
int index;  // Index of next free pair.
```

Then use C standard `qsort()`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...

int comparePairs(const void *pairA, const void *pairB) 
{ 
    Pair* a = (Pair*)pairA;
    Pair* b = (Pair*)pairB;

    return strlen(a->word) - strlen(b->word);
}

qsort(pairs, index, sizeof(Pair), comparePairs);
```

The `index` would start at `0`, which indicates the next free `Pair` is at that index. Adding an element would be:

```
pairs[index].word  = someWord; // someWord must be allocated elsewhere!
pairs[index].count = 1;
index++;
```

Note that, because your structure only has a `char` pointer, that the `someWord` must be allocated elsewhere. Without automatic memory management this is going to be rather cumbersome. A better alternative would be to `strcpy()` the word in by using the following structure:

```
typedef struct pair
{
    char word[50]; // Assumes a word is NEVER longer than 49 characters.
    int  count;
} Pair;
```

Adding a new element would then become:

```
strncpy(pairs[index].word, someWord, 50 - 1);
pairs[index].count = 1;
index++;
```

The `strncpy()` above copies at most 49 characters. You need to make sure you chose this 50 or whatever size wisely to make sure `strncpy()` never starts chopping off ends of your very long words.

But of course to know if you have to add a new or simply increment the count of an existing one, you'd first need to search through the existing `Pair`s with a simple loop.

Comment: @4386427 Thanks, I was too quick.

Comment: How to add elements to that structure?

Comment: @RobHannigan I extended the answer.

Comment: Thanks, works great, I just adjusted comparison function to: return c->count < b->count; This is what I really wanted, but your answer is really cool.